# regex pattern not matching continuous groups

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am trying the following pattern :

```
[,;\" ](.+?\/.+?)[\",; ]
```

in the following string:

['"**text/html**,***application/xhtml+xml***,**application/xml**;q=0.9;q
    =0.8"']

It matches the bold text but not the italic one. Why?

I want to extract `text/html`, `application/xhtml+xml` and `application/xml`. It is extracting 1st and 3rd but not the middle one

Comment: There is a comma inside the character set. Do you mean you do not want to use a comma as a boundary? Remove it, see [`[;" ](.+?\/.+?)["; ]`](https://regex101.com/r/GeM7ks/1).

Comment: No, I want to use comma as a boundary. But it is not matching 'application/xhtml+xml'

Comment: Then what are you so surprised at? The pattern will stop at any `,`. What are your pattern requirements?

Comment: I want to extract text/html, application/xhtml+xml and application/xml. It is extracting 1st and 3rd but not the middle one.

Comment: Good, use [`[,;" ](.+?\/.+?)(?=[,"; ])`](https://regex101.com/r/GeM7ks/2). What is your programming language?

Comment: I am working with python. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it will work in Python. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last `[,"; ]` consumes the `,` after `text/html` and thus, at the next iteration, when the regex engine searches for a match, the first `[,;" ]` cannot match that comma. Hence, you lose one match.

You may turn the trailing `[,"; ]` into a non-consuming pattern, a positive lookahead, or better, since the matches cannot contain the delimiters, use a negated character class approach:

```
[,;" ]([^/,;" ]+/[^/,;" ]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GeM7ks/3). If there can be more than 1 `/` inside the expected matches, remove `/` char from the second character class.

**Details**

- `[,;" ]` - a comma, `;`, `"`, or space
- `([^/,;" ]+/[^/,;" ]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars that is not `/`, `,`. `;`, `"` and space, `/` and then again any one or more chars that is not `/`, `,`. `;`, `"` and space as many as possible

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Lzxr1y):

```
import re
rx = r'[,;" ]([^/,;" ]+/[^/,;" ]+)'
s = """['"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9;q =0.8"']"""
res = re.findall(rx, s)
print(res) # => ['text/html', 'application/xhtml+xml', 'application/xml']
```

Comment: In the string ";q=0.9,lol/lol;", I just want the lol/lol. If I use the pattern I described above, it gives me ;q=0.9,lol/lol

Comment: Perfect solution! I am actually quite happy right now. Anything I can do for you?